# VBA Excel and R

Tags: r, excel, vba

I am looking for a way to connect and communicate with R from excel. The solution I found is Rexcel which seems to be almost 10 years old and does not work with Excel 365. Is there a new way available to interact with R from Excel?

Comment: Depends on the kind of interaction. The most flexible way is through [COM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model), and I have done this heavily in Python with [Pywin32](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/). For R, there is [RDCOMClient](https://github.com/omegahat/RDCOMClient), but I'm not sure it's still very active. If you only want to export data to an Excel file, there are much simpler means ([openxlsx](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/openxlsx/), for instance).

Comment: Here's an alternative: make a parameterized API (e.g., `plumber`) that exports data; from there, Excel allows *"Data > Get Data > From Other Sources > From Web"*, and depending on the returned format, it can be imported directly or with some drill-down logic. One link that demonstrates the Excel side is https://www.codementor.io/@benniejayguevarra/importing-public-web-api-to-excel-no-coding-required-14bzfy4nev, though I have not tested it in depth. Good luck!

Comment: You can also use the XLConnect package which allows you to insert data into the Excel file and force the Excel file to be recalculated (see https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/XLConnect/XLConnect.pdf). I also use a lot RDOMClient and it works very well for me.

Comment: Last time I checked (2021), Python package **xlwings** handled some edge cases (e. g. Excel's merged cell nightmare) beyond what was available via dedicated R packages. For the rest, **{openxlsx}** worked just great. Note that you can use Python pkgs under R with **{reticulate}** - if you really need to go down the rabbit hole of beautifully formatted Excel reports ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the R package RDCOMClient to control / modify an Excel file. For example, you can open an Excel file and modify it as you wish from R, write a data.frame from R to the Excel file, etc. Here is a simple example :

```
library(RDCOMClient)
xlApp <- COMCreate("Excel.Application")
xlApp[["DisplayAlerts"]] <- FALSE
xlApp[["Visible"]] <- TRUE

path_To_Excel_File <- "C:/my_excel_File.xlsx"
xlWbk <- xlApp$Workbooks()$Open(path_To_Excel_File, ReadOnly = TRUE)
xlWbk$Sheets(1)$Range("A1")$Value()
```